# Saved a file to blobstore and am now getting __BlobFileIndex__ kind error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Not sure what I did wrong but on the `dev_appserver` I saved a NDB `BlobKeyProperty` in a gae app and now if I try to load the entity from the database I get a :

> KindError: No model class found for kind '__BlobFileIndex__'. Did you forget to import it?

I can pull up the entity in /_ah/admin and it looks fine... Any suggestions on what is going on ?

Code that I used to save the field into the `BlobKeyProperty`

```
 blob = files.blobstore.create(
            _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=self.data.filename,
            mime_type=self.MIME_TYPE
        )
 with files.open(blob, 'a') as f:
     f.write(self.data.file.read())
     files.finalize(blob)
 key =  files.blobstore.get_blob_key(blob)
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

---

**Edit**:

I also just noticed, if I go into the /_ah/admin look at something, and then go back to the app I get a :

> KindError: No model class found for kind '_AhAdminXsrfToken_'. Did you forget to import it?

So something is obviously going wrong (I noticed *AhAdminXsrfToken* is a `db.Model` ) not sure if that helps explain the issue...